# Overflow Exception in parsing integer

Tags: c#, overflow

I'm trying to do the "Xor" operation. Firstly i convert two strings into binary, i loop on each character of the first ch in first string and the second string to xor them together, but i keep getting "overflow exception was unhandled by the user code"

```
r1 = 0; r2 = 0; s1 = ""; s2 = "";
  //lastW    ="10001011100001001110101100000001"

            r1 = int.Parse(lastW); //Here where i get the exception
```

I tried also using

```
 r1 = Convert.ToInt32(lastW);
```

but i get the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Your string holds a number slightly larger than "ten nonillion" in base 10. That's quite a lot larger than the [maximum value of an int32](https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum+value+of+int32).

You can use `Convert.ToInt32(lastW, 2)` to convert from a binary string (the second optional parameter of `Convert.ToInt32` accepts a radix from which to convert).

Comment: It needs to be Convert.ToInt64(lastW, 2). It's two big for an int32.

Comment: How your answer is differ from an accepted answer in proposed duplicate?

Comment: It's not different, but it can't hurt to answer this question directly to make the solution more visible to the OP